# get the index of cookie from list in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, list, lambda

In the following code I'm having cookies e.g : `__RequestVerificationToken_LlsZQ2=Z_nK9nEK9xNmHA34qmw...`, I want the exact name of cookie i.e `__RequestVerificationToken_LlsZQ2`

```
var headers = actionContext.Request.Headers;
if(headers.GetCookies().Any(x => x.Cookies.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("_RequestVerificationToken_")))) 
{
   var tokenCookie = headers.GetCookies()
                  .Select(c => c[headers.GetCookies()[0].Cookies[0].Name.ToString()])
                  .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I'm getting the name of cookie with the help of `headers.GetCookies()[0].Cookies[0].Name.ToString()`. but if I'm not sure about the index of the cookie, then how can I get its index?

PS In `__RequestVerificationToken_LlsZQ2` the `__RequestVerificationToken_` will remain as it is.
I tried `headers.GetCookies().IndexOf(x => x.Cookies.Any(y => y.Name.Contains("_RequestVerificationToken_")))` but it gives error.

Comment: On my end the name starts with ".AspNetCore.Antiforgery"  So get all cookies, and iterate through the array to find the one that starts with/contains that.  You can view those in the browser's inspector.  (xhr requests)

Comment: Btw, from the docs it looks like the name is generated based on the server path... probably a one-way hash of that.  You can set it to anything you like though...  why are you needing the name of the cookie?  (just curious)

Comment: Is a LINQ query required? If not, why not just use a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Create a substring starting from the 0 index of the header variable and ending before the "=" char. This should get you the name of the cookie.

```
string tokenCookie = headers.Substring(0, headers.IndexOf("="));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.